# Hide NavBar but show status bar with background

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, statusbar

My nav bar is setup to hide on scroll but it also takes the background color of my status bar with it when it goes, leaving white status bar text on top of my content as I scroll. I want it to look similar to the way many apps do it where if my navbar and status bar have an orange background with white text, when the scroll happens and the navbar hides, the status bar retains the orange background.

Update1:

Tried adding a subview of 20 to the view but its not showing up. I may be missing something since this is my first attempt at creating an app without IB.

I put this code into my TableViewController. I tried tableview., view. and super.view. and none of them seemed to work.

```
let statusBarBG = UIView()
        statusBarBG.backgroundColor = UIColor.rgb(248, green: 148, blue: 6)
        super.view?.addSubview(statusBarBG)
        super.view?.addContstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(20)]", views: statusBarBG)
        super.view?.addContstraintsWithFormat("H:|[v0]|", views: statusBarBG)
```

**Update 2:**

So after trying a few things, my view appears but its under the navbar and scrolls with the tableview which causes it to disappear when the user scrolls.

FeedTVController:UITableViewController

```
 let statusBarBG = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: -44, width: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.width, height: 20))
            statusBarBG.backgroundColor = .redColor()  //UIColor.rgb(248, green: 148, blue: 6)
            self.view?.addSubview(statusBarBG)
```

App Delegate:

```
let feedController = FeedTVController()
        let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: feedController)
        let tabBarController = TabBarController()
        tabBarController.setViewControllers([vc1, vc2, vc3], animated: true)
        window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
```

Comment: Can't you just put a UIView at the top of your view that's 20 points tall and the correct color?

Answer (score 3):

After looking around for a whole day I couldn't find a proper solution for this case. Thinking in a logical way I came up with a solution, I hope that helps the people having the same issue.

By default there is no Status Bar background view so we need to create one and place it under the Status Bar but above the Navigation Bar:

```
On viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.hidesBarsOnSwipe = true

    /* creates a View using the navigation bar frame to place under the status bar but above the navigation bar */

    let statusBarView = UIView()
    statusBarView.backgroundColor = .blue
    statusBarView.frame = UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame
    UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.addSubview(statusBarView)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the background color of your SuperView (ViewController View) to orange(or whatever color you want as default for statusbar.

Answer (score 0):

There's no code so there are two ways you could be hiding your navBar:

If you're hiding a subclass manually so it's hiding relative to how much the user scrolls up (like Facebook): Then instead of hiding your navigation bar all the way, hide it with 20 points from its bottom left on the screen.

If you're hiding navBar with the built-in animated hide: Then add a subview that's connected to the top of the container and is 20 points high with the same background color, so when navigationbar goes away, the subview is at the top.

Comment: currently I'm doing the latter. I tried to create a subview that should do that but its not working. I'll add it to my question.

Comment: Ok then you should add a UIView with `height` of 20 points and set its AutoLayout constraints such that it sticks to the top of the container.

Comment: Thats what I did. addContstraintsWithFormat("V:|[v0(20)]", views: statusBarBG)

Comment: @MichaelWilliams You need to use `"V:[topGuide]-0-[v0(20)]"` so your view sticks to the navigation bar and not the top of the root view which goes under the navigation bar.

Comment: topGuide is an invalid argument according to the console

Comment: @MichaelWilliams What's the view hierarchy? Could you please post your code where you add subviews and where you set the constraints?

Comment: @MichaelWilliams also why are you adding a subview to `super.view` and not `self.view` ?

Comment: check my post update. I was trying everything to get it to appear. super.view was the last thing I had tried so I posted it with that.